# Are gpg -sta and gpg --clearsign commands same thing?

Tags: gnupg

Are `gpg -sta` and `gpg --clearsign` commands same thing? I believe so, but it is not obvious from the man page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the man page on my system:

> *If -t (but not --textmode) is used together with armoring and signing,
>   this  enables clearsigned messages. This kludge is needed for
>   command-line compatibility with command-line versions of PGP; normally
>   you would use --sign or --clearsign to select the type of the
>   signature.*

Seems pretty clear to me.

Also, I *think* these kinds of questions should be on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: If you feel a question should be moved, just flag it so newer users aren't tempted to cross post